# Magento 2 WSDL link

Tags: api, wsdl, magento2-dev-beta

I see that Magento 2 still has a SOAP API.
I'm not able to find the URL to the `WSDL`.

I've tried this so far:

`$HOME/api/soap/index/?wsdl` and `$HOME/api/soap/index/?wsdl=1`

Comment: Perhaps a specific store view is required? https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Model/Soap/Server.php#L164

Comment: @B00MER Still not getting it :|

Comment: @Marius, How to invoke magento 2 api? plz.. let me know with example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was playing with API today. It looks URLs like these work on beta2:

```
$HOME/soap/?services=customerAccountManagementV1&wsdl
$HOME/soap/?services=customerGroupRepositoryV1&wsdl
```

Service name translation is being done in `Magento\Webapi\Helper\Data::getServiceNameParts()` and there are examples in docblock there. Examples are probably outdated, but they show general idea.

Comment: hi, how to invoke magento 2 api? plz.. let me know with example

Answer (score 7):

And we changed it...

If you're looking for Magento Dev RC - SOAP WSDL's the new pattern is like so (with some examples)

```
$HOME/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=catalogProductRepositoryV1
$HOME/soap/default?wsdl=1&services=customerAccountManagementV1
```

To figure out what the service is called look at both the module name (also namespace) and it's webapi.xml to find the class name that's being exposed as a service.  Drop any redundant name spaces/naming ( api, services, interface ) and combine as [module namespace][class name].

Comment: To get the list of all available wsdl services use this url: $HOME/soap/default?wsdl_list=1